# Making a proper fade-in and fade-out for a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried to put a slideshow into my HTML using CSS and js.
I want to execute two functions simultaneously, namely fading in the new slide and fading out the current slide.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
var timer;

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  { 
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", " ");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active"; 
  slides[slideIndex-1].className += " fade";
  timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 10000);
}
} 

function stopSlide(){
 clearTimeout (timer);
}

function resumeSlide(){
    timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 10000);
}

function fade (){
  slides[slideIndex].className += " fadein";
  slides[slideIndex-1].className += " fadeout";
}
```

```css
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  left: 50%;
}
/* Fading animation */
.fadein {
  -moz-animation-name: fadein;
  -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
   animation-name: fadein;
   animation-duration: 4s;
   animation-timing-function: linear;

}

.fadeout {
  -moz-animation-name: fadeout;
  -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
   animation-name: fadeout;
   animation-duration: 4s;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
            from {
transform: translateX(-1000px);
            }

            to {
transform: translateX(0px);
            }
        }


@keyframes fadein {
            from {
transform: translateX(-1000px);
            }

            to {
transform: translateX(0px);
            }
        }


@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
            from {
transform: translateX(0px);
            }

            to {
transform: translateX(1000px);
            }
        }

@keyframes fadeout {
            from {
transform: translateX(0px);
            }

            to {
transform: translateX(1000px);
            }
        }
```

```html
<div id="slide"> <h1>This is my slideshow.</h1> </div> <br/>
<div class="slideshow-container container" onmouseover="stopSlide()" onmouseleave="resumeSlide()">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080 ?Text=Digital.com" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image4" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
</div>


<br>
<div style="text-align:center" >
  <span class="dot" onclick="dotclick()"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span>
   <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
```

I'm kind of at a dead-end here, since this is my first attempt.
I've used a template from w3schools for the slider.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what exactly is not working for you? Both animations?

Comment: Could you specify what your _issue_ is?

Comment: @King11 If I only use the fadein or fadeout animation it (somewhat) works.

The general issue is, that the image fades in *or* out, but the next slide does not fade in. The current slide just leaves the box.

Comment: I see you've updated your html code now. I'll have another look

Comment: I do have a dot class, I forgot to include it in the snippet.
The code does also run, I'm mainly concerned about the fade/transition, as that part is not working.

Comment: Ok, Ill give it a look. So you just want the fade out to happen and then the fade in to happen after the fade out is finished?

Comment: Preferably I want to "push" out the current image with the new one in a fade animation.
I also want to understand **why** as I'm just beginning to learn JS. :)

Comment: @Scurra how much do you want your code to change?

Comment: I'd love to keep it at the current core or some version I can understand!

Comment: ok, no problem, still working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the transitions work, `display` should be removed. Transitions does not work on `display` using pure JavaScript. I added a few lines of code setting the opacity and transition time within your `for-loops`. I also added two `.css` classes for the `div` elements and when the `div` is `active` and gave those classes positioning and width for the `div` elements. Also for demo purposes I lowered the time from 10 seconds to 3 seconds. I also took out a lot of unneeded code that pertained to animation. I did not touch the `dots` code so you would have to figure out what you want to do with that. I tried not to change the code too much per your request. I just deleted what was not needed. Hopefully this helps you at least figure out the transitions problem.

```css
.mySlides{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.mySlides.active{
  position: static;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  left: 50%;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide"> <h1>This is my slideshow.</h1> </div> <br/>
<div class="slideshow-container container" onmouseover="stopSlide()" onmouseleave="resumeSlide()">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080 ?Text=Digital.com" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image4" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
</div>


<br>
<div style="text-align:center" >
  <span class="dot" onclick="dotclick()"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span>
   <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
var timer;

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  { 
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.transition  = "3.0s";
    slides[i].style.opacity = "0";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", " ");
  }
   slides[slideIndex-1].style.transition  = "3.0s";
   slides[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
 
  dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("active"); 
  
  timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 3000);
}
} 

function stopSlide(){
 clearTimeout (timer);
}

function resumeSlide(){
    timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 3000);
}


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However one thing I still don't understand sadly.
How can I change the value from   `slides[slideIndex-1].style.transition  = "3.0s";` ?
If I alter it in any way, it just bricks the timer. Can I connect it to a pre-written CSS transition? That way I could put a proper transition from left 0% to left 100% and let the Slides, well, slide-out.

Comment: @Scurra glad I could help. If this was the answer to this question, could you mark this as the accepted answer and ask a new question about the `.css` transitions? I'll be glad to help you on that as well. It should just be a new question since I answered this one.Just add a link the the question below this comment and let me know, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: It would be great if this wasn't so much dependent on the number of frames.  Please check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803373/making-a-proper-fade-in-and-fade-out-for-a-slideshow/64064866#64064866

Comment: But if you remove display=block, you can't use this slideshow as a banner that fills the browser from right to left and fit into the whole scheme of html code. How can you remove display block and still use this slide show as a banner on your website?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I do it (no claim of originality, basic idea cowardly stolen). Very clear and elementary, it works for any number of images, no preloading necessary, no jquery, pure JS, no CSS transitions, no classes, and works in older browsers.

In the HTML, you need two `img` nodes, called `img` (with opacity 1) and `imgbottom` (with opacity 0), that you can even append with JS:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "someimage.jpg";
var imgbottom = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute("position", "absolute");
imgbottom.setAttribute("position", "absolute");
imgbottom.style.opacity = 0;
somediv.appendChild(img);
somediv.appendChild(imgbottom);
```

The nodes must be with `position:absolute` style in its container to guarantee that the images appear over each other. Then, all the trick is done in the `imgbottom.onload` method:

```
var timer;
var fadetime = 500; //miliseconds of transition
imgbottom.onload = function () {                                                                                
  var opac = 0;
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (opac >= 1) {
      img.src = imgbottom.src;
      img.style.opacity = 1;
      imgbottom.style.opacity = 0;
      img.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + 100 + ')'; // IE fallback
      imgbottom.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + 0 + ')'; // IE fallback
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      img.style.opacity = 1-opac;
      imgbottom.style.opacity = opac;
      img.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + (1-opac)*100 + ')'; // IE fallback
      imgbottom.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opac*100 + ')'; // IE fallback
      opac += 25.0/fadetime;
    }
  }, fadetime/50);
}
```

To activate the transition, just load an image into `imgbottom`:

```
imgbottom.src = "otherimage.jpg";
```