# Im try to get the fade in and out to work in my slideshow

Tags: css, typescript, sveltekit

My problem is that the fading only works on the first time the page loads and only on the first image
the rest the fading the doesn't work on any image

this is what i have done in css and add it to `class="banner-items fade"`

```
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

and other things with svelte transition:fade.

### Here is mode html is compoment

```
<div
    class="maestro-list"
    on:mouseenter={() => clearInterval(interval)} // pause and unpause
    on:mouseleave={() => {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
            current = (current + 1) % images.length
        }, delay)
    }}
>
    {#each images as image, index}
        <transition {index} {current} {delay}>
            <div class="banner-item">
                <span class="pic">
                    <img
                        src={image}
                        alt="dragon"
                        loading="lazy"
                        style="position:relative; display: {index === current ? 'block' : 'none'}"
                    />
                </span>
                <a class="banner_lnk" href="/">.</a>
            </div>
        </transition>
    {/each}
    <div class="num">
        {#each images as _, index}
            <span                      
                class="dot"
                tabindex="0"
                role="button"
                on:click={() => setcurrent(index)} //dot pagination
                class:active={index === current}
                on:keypress={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === "Enter") {
                        setcurrent(index)
                    }
                }}
            />
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

### Script Typescript

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte"

    const images: string[] = ["/img-new-fixed.png", "/placeholder-9.png"]
    let current = 0
    let delay = 8000 // 8 seconds

    function setcurrent(index: number) {
        current = index
        clearInterval(interval)
        interval = setInterval(transition, delay)
    }

    function transition() {
        current = (current + 1) % images.length
    }

    let interval: NodeJS.Timeout

    onMount(() => {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
            current = (current + 1) % images.length
        }, delay)
    })

    onDestroy(() => {
        clearInterval(interval)
    })
</script>
```

one thing that come to mind that i haven't done is
[is this example from stackoverflow the last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803373/making-a-proper-fade-in-and-fade-out-for-a-slideshow)

heres a reference where i got it the idea for the [Banner](https://www.webtoons.com/en/)

Comment: Here is an example of an image carousel I found that is similar to that Banner link you gave (https://svelte.dev/repl/78bee610166a486a9304b9bfbeb77887?version=3.20.1). I believe in your example you're applying the CSS transition at the start for each image, which means they play that one time and are not reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way making use of [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions?retiredLocale=de) and Svelte's [class:directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5dfe8623529d4633a1104696a0f2782f?version=3.55.0)

```
<script>
    import {urls} from './urls'
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    let index = 0
    let interval

    const start = () => interval = setInterval(() => index = (index + 1) % urls.length, 2500)
    const stop = () => clearInterval(interval)

    onMount(() => {
        start()
        return () => stop() //executed when component is destroyed
    })

    function handleMarkerClick(i) {
        stop()
        index = i
    }
</script>

<div id="carousel">
    {#each urls as url, i}
    <img src={url} alt=""
             class:current-img={index === i}
             />
    {/each}
    <div id="carousel-nav">
        {#each urls as _, i}
        <svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" 
                            class:current-marker="{index === i}"
                            on:click="{() => handleMarkerClick(i)}"
                            />
        </svg>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #carousel {
        position: relative;
        height: 500px;
    }
    img {
        position: absolute;
        inset: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 500ms ease-out;
    }
    .current-img {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #carousel-nav {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        bottom: 5%;
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
        gap: .5rem;
    }
    circle {
        fill: grey;
        transition: fill 500ms ease-out;
    }
    .current-marker {
        fill: white;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Svelte, but if I were to do this in Vanilla HTML/CSS/JS, I'd want to have the `animation-fill-mode` set to `forwards` on the animation and I'd also want to attach/remove the `.fade` class as the buttons are clicked from the appropriate elements and reset the opacity.

Here's a VanillaJS implementation, maybe that'll help you to see what you're missing using this framework?

```js
const slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".slide"));
const buttonGroup = document.querySelector("#button-group");

buttonGroup.addEventListener("click", fadeSlides);

function fadeSlides(event) {
    const slideID = event.target.textContent;
    const slideSelector = `slide-${slideID}`;
    slides.forEach((el) => {
        if (el.id === slideSelector) {
            el.classList.add("fade");
        } else {
            el.classList.remove("fade");
            el.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Fade Example</title>
        <script defer src="app.js"></script>
        <style>
            #slideshow {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
            }

            #button-group {
                margin-top: 12px;
            }

            .slide {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                opacity: 0;
            }

            #slide-1 {
                background-color: red;
                opacity: 1;
            }

            #slide-2 {
                background-color: green;
            }

            #slide-3 {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .fade {
                animation-name: fade;
                animation-duration: 1.5s;
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }

            @keyframes fade {
                from {
                    opacity: 0;
                }
                to {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slideshow">
            <div class="slide" id="slide-1"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-2"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="button-group">
            <button id="button-1">1</button>
            <button id="button-2">2</button>
            <button id="button-3">3</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```